# Trigger click after load page

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, triggers, click

I'm working with a wordpress theme and I need to activate a button when the page loads, but none of the following has worked for me (my button has the ID "reset"):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#reset")[0].click();
});
```

--

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#reset").click();
})
```

--

```
$(window).load(function(){
      $('#reset').click();
});
```

I put the code in the header or in the page where i need to activate the button, but does not work.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you tell us what type of element the button is and that either is or is not an anchor that you're expecting to click to go to another page.

Comment: I am making this page:
http://loscontratistas.mx/san2015/recetas-sm/
the problem is that masonry elements not shown well (sometimes). But if I click a button filter or the button "reset" then the elements are displayed correctly.
What I want to do is force this button for all the items displayed in the right way when the page loads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I give you example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/72dnhvuf/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#reset").click();
})
```

the code above should work.

Comment: I see that it works in the demo. Unfortunately I can not make it work on my site.

Comment: please inspect element in browser, you get an error on it.

I think you add double jquery.js load. please load one jquery.js, remove the other one.

Comment: try to remove this code (add the bottom of your page), `<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`. it will fix the jquery undefined error.

Comment: if I remove this line "ScrollReveal" stops working and also "Isotope" :s

Comment: But you load 2 jquery.js, and its make the page error. `<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>` (at bottom of page) and `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://loscontratistas.mx/san2015/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.11.1"></script>` (at top page, inside head tag). place the `$(document).ready` code after you load the jquery.js. and also choice one jquery.js load.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript does not allow seamless programmatic triggering of an actual click event.

What you could do is

1. declare the click callback as a separate, named function

e.g.

```
function myClickCallback(e) {
  // Do stuff here
}
```

2. Set this as the click callback of your button (e.g. `$('#reset').on('click', myClickCallback)`).
3. Invoke the callback when the page loads (e.g. `$(document).ready(myClickCallback);`)

I am not sure why you 'd want this functionality, since it sounds weird. From reading your description, by "activating", you could also mean enabling the button. To do that you should do something like the following

```
$(document).on('ready', function (e){
    $('#reset').removeAttr('disabled');
});
```

Comment: I need click the "reset" button on this page:
http://loscontratistas.mx/san2015/recetas-sm/

this is because the Masonry elements is not displayed correctly until I click on a filter or the "reset" button

Answer (score 1):

You may need to refer to it using `jQuery` instead of `$`:

> The jQuery library included with WordPress is set to the [noConflict()](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/avoid-conflicts-other-libraries/) mode...

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#jQuery_noConflict_Wrappers

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#reset").trigger('click');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the function Trigger with the event click

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#reset").trigger('click');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This what works for me:

```
$(function () {
        $('#btnUpdatePosition').click();  
});
```

On the button event, the JQuery binding event doesn't work:

```
$('#btnUpdatePosition').click(function () {
            alert('test again');
        });
```

But it works when I added the event on attribute declaration:

```
<input type="button" value="Update" id="btnUpdatePosition" onclick="alert('Click has been called')" />
```

You can also call if you have a function on element:

```
<input type="button" value="Update" id="btnUpdatePosition" onclick="fncShow();" />
```